# Overlaying drawing with p5js on top of image in HTML

Tags: html, css, p5.js

I am really struggling trying to figure this one out. I am trying to overlay the circles ontop of an image. Preferably having the image in HTML. For whatever reason I can't seem to get this to work

```
var img;
function setup() {
createCanvas(800,800);
img=loadImage("DSC04051.jpeg");
function draw() {
image(img,0,0,);
circle(mouseX, mouseY, 100);
}
```

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve] and ask a specific technical question about your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is enough code and a MRE ... with a bug, @Sophia you are missing a closing curly bracket at the end of setup. Just before `function` in `function draw()`, that fixed you have the elipse over the image. Is this what you want?

Comment: You can use `position()` to abs position an HTML image under the canvas i think, not sure though.

Comment: It is working to make a circle over the image, but it is not working to draw the circles continuously. That is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: That's because in every draw loop the call to the image erases the previous ellipse, to persist either move image call to setup, or you will need to store each ellipse in an array and draw all of them in each frame again

Comment: Okay I manage to fix that particular issue thank you! but now the image keeps disappearing every time I execute the KeyPressed Function. https://editor.p5js.org/selwilton-lowly/sketches/kNLXR6qHZ

Answer (score 0):

When you call `clear()` it clears the screen :)

You can then call the image again.

Like this

```js
function preload() {
  img1 = loadImage("DSC04051.jpeg");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  // here it will affect the image in first display
  tint(100, 200);
  image(img1, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    circle(mouseX, mouseY, 100);
  }
}

function keyPressed() {
  clear();
  // just call it again to clear screen from drawings
  tint(100, 200);
  image(img1, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
}
```

I also mooved the first `tint()` to setup, so it will affect the image from the begining.